# Return column name in Dataframe with boolean check

Tags: pandas, boolean, python-3.6

I have the following Dataframe with booleans

```
Out[25]: 
                0     1      2
Date                          
2007-01-03  False  True  False
2007-01-04  False  False True
2007-01-05  False  True  False
2007-01-08  True   False False
2007-01-09  False  True  False
```

I am looking to get a DF which returns the column index for the column value 'True' for every row.

Required Output:

```
            0
Date                          
2007-01-03  1
2007-01-04  2
2007-01-05  1
2007-01-08  0
2007-01-09  1
```

what is the best pythonic way to do this pls?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If only one `True` per row use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['new'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
                0      1      2 new
Date                               
2007-01-03  False   True  False   1
2007-01-04  False  False   True   2
2007-01-05  False   True  False   1
2007-01-08   True  False  False   0
2007-01-09  False   True  False   1
```

If multiple `True`s:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.index[x]), axis=1)
print (df)
                0      1      2  new
Date                                
2007-01-03  False   True   True  1,2
2007-01-04  False  False   True    2
2007-01-05  False   True  False    1
2007-01-08   True  False  False    0
2007-01-09  False   True  False    1
```

Another solution:

```
print (['{}, '.format(x) for x in df.columns])
['0, ', '1, ', '2, ']

s = np.where(df, ['{}, '.format(x) for x in df.columns], '')
df['new'] = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], index=df.index)
print (df)
                0      1      2   new
Date                                 
2007-01-03  False   True   True  1, 2
2007-01-04  False  False   True     2
2007-01-05  False   True  False     1
2007-01-08   True  False  False     0
2007-01-09  False   True  False     1
```